# Meteor wrapAsync works, but restarts server after completion

Tags: asynchronous, meteor, synchronous

I'm trying to learn how to use Meteor's [wrapAsync](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_wrapasync) helper. I want to use it to call an async function sequentially (not simultaneously).  Though my code works, when it completes, the server restarts, which makes me wonder if there is a bug in my code. Unfortunately, there is no message saying why it restarted.  Am I missing something?

The code is below and also on my [MeteorPad demo](http://meteorpad.com/pad/L33qEDtFnDGeY3qGg/Synchronized%20AsyncIO%20using%20wrapAsync).

```js
var doAsyncIO = function (num, callback) {
  setTimeout( function () {
    // wrapAsync will use the following callback as the basis of returning results synchronously
    callback(null, 'This is delayed result #' + num );  // nodeJS form: cb(error,result)
  }, 2500);  // wait 2.5 seconds before returning result
};

// Now create a synchronous version of doAsyncIO that sleeps, not blocks
// so that the CPU can do other tasks while waiting for the result

var doSyncIO = Meteor.wrapAsync(doAsyncIO);

// Now call doSyncIO twice sequentially (not simultaneously)

console.log('\n*** Starting first call to doSyncIO');
var result1 = doSyncIO(1);
console.log('result1:', result1); 

// The following block runs after result1 is set (which is what I want)

console.log('\n*** Starting second call to doSyncIO');
var result2 = doSyncIO(2);
console.log('result2:', result2);
```

After a code change and *after* the console logs appear on the terminal, the terminal says the server restarts with no reason provided which makes me wonder if there is a bug in my code!

2015-04-19 Update: the restart message may not actually indicate a problem since it only shows up after a code change.  Perhaps it's simply the standard restart message. Nevertheless, it seems like the restart message should really occur before the console logs.

Feel free to comment or fork my [MeteorPad demo](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_wrapasync) though to see if it's something else.

Comment: is that really what you are running or did you simplify your code for the question? My suspicion would be that your actual code writes into the project directory somewhere, causing a server restart. Could that be?

Comment: The MeteorPad you have provided does not show any weird behaviour so I side with @ChristianFritz on this matter, something must happen to your project files.

Comment: try it with `Meteor.setTimeout`, it's possibly going wonky since setTimeout doesn't bind to a new fiber.

Comment: Thanks for checking. That's really the code, but within a `Meteor.isServer` block.  You can see the issue if you make a minor change to the MeteorPad.  `Meteor.setTimeout` didn't help, but now that I look more closely, during the initial code run, the terminal message **after** my console.logs is `Started you app`.  Then when I make code changes, the message after my console logs is `Meteor server restarted`.  I also tried using `Meteor.startup`, but no diff. So I guess there's no problem, just surprising to see restart messages come so late.